# Is it possible that the word virgin originally had two meanings?

Tags: greek, meaning

I wasn't sure whether to post this here, or on mythology stack exchange. Since it deals with the origin of a word, I choose here. But if I am wrong, tell me and I will move it.

The originally meaning of the word [**virgin**](http://www.topix.com/forum/afam/TKOGRLKVQPTAPMJSC/original-meaning-of-virgin) meant unmarried, one-in-herself, not belonging to a man-a woman.
The modern meaning means never experienced copulation.

But, I have read a Greek Myth that suggests both meanings were true. In short, the 50 daughters of one king was set to marry the 50 sons of another. In some way the kings were related(cousins/brothers). The father of the daughters was against it and ordered them to kill their husbands on their wedding night. The 50 couples married and 49 of the daughters obeyed their father and killed their partner. The one that didn't only did so because of her desire to remain a virgin.

This is why I ask. She is married, therefore, not a virgin, in the original respect. Yet, she did not kill her husband out of his respect for her to remain a virgin, in the modern respect. Is is plausible that both definitions were true in ancient times.

Comment: "Virgin" is an English word, yet you talk about a Greek myth. Are you actually asking about the English word (derived from Latin "virgo"), or some Greek word, and if the latter, which one? The fact that it has been glossed as "virgin" in English is not something that you can use to draw a one-to-one correspondence. Could it have been [this word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%B8%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) perhaps? It does have a few connected meaning.

Comment: I think, this question does not deserve *that* many downvotes. We are here to learn, and the OP **has their right for misunderstanding** when asking a question, provided that they demonstrated a fair attempt to self-answer the question and matching other basic Stack Exchange requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The English word *virgin* derives (ultimately) from Latin [virgo](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvirgo). In Latin it has one meaning (refers to one concept), though it has metaphorical extensions based on that one meaning (for example, the constellation known as *Virgo* is not a human at all). It might translate into a number of English words. The word does not come from Greek, and it would not have appeared in a Greek myth, though perhaps it appeared in a Greek myth translated into Latin.

Details of the origin and meaning of the English word are available in the Oxford English Dictionary, where the earliest sense of the word is "a. A person who has no sexual experience; a person who has never engaged in sexual activity or (sometimes spec.) never had penetrative sex". Contemporary English has extended the meaning metaphorically in many ways, e.g. "virgin plastic" (not recycled), "virgin mojito" (no alcohol). It's not that the word in English has two (or more meanings), it's that the meaning has changed – broadened – over time, so that it does not just refer to young females who have not had sex.